# tinymce dynamic add mutiple menu items to dropdown menu-all onclick direct to last menu item click

Tags: javascript, for-loop, tinymce, editor, tinymce-4

I am using tinymce + [tinymce-variable](https://github.com/ambassify/tinymce-variable). I want to create drop down menu that have dynamic menu item. Based on items from sql, I am able to create multiple drop down menu. I created each menu item using `editor.addMenuItem()` inside the loop.

```
for(i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{
    template_var    =data[i]['variable'];       
    text_val        =template_var.replace(/\s/g , " ");
    editor.addMenuItem(template_var,
    {
        text    :text_val,
        context :'newmenu',
        onclick :function ()
        {               
            editor.plugins.variable.addVariable(template_var);
        }
    })
}
```

The problem I am facing is when I click any of the menu item, it adding last menu item to the editor and not the menu item that I have clicked. I guess, It `overwrite the editor.plugins.variable.addVariable(template_var); to last menu item for all menu item`. How is that possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A click on menu item directly go to specific line `editor.plugins.variable.addVariable(template_var);` of particular menu item. When we execute in loop, it only find one line of this code.That is why click on any menu item perform click only on last menu item because this code overridden for last item at end of loop. So, I solve it this way. I concatenate the `editor.addMenuItem()` code for execution for each menu item as string.Then, I execute that string in `setup :function (editor){} of tinymce.init({})` using `eval()`. In this way, when we click on menu item, it can find `editor.plugins.variable.addVariable(template_var);` for particular menu item.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
variablenames_concat='';
addmenu_concat      ='';
for(j=0;j<data.length;j++)
        {
            variablenames_concat+=data[j]['variable']+',';
            template_var        =data[j]['variable'];
            text_val            =template_var.replace(/\s/g , " ");//remove underscore
            //string concatenate editor.addMenuItem for each of item 
            addmenu_concat      +='editor.addMenuItem("'+template_var+'",{text  : "'+text_val+'",context: "newmenu",onclick: function (){editor.plugins.variable.addVariable("'+template_var+'");}});';
        }
variablenames_concat = variablenames_concat.replace(/,\s*$/, "");//remove last coma

tinymce.init
({
  selector  : 'textarea',
  height    :  500, 
  plugins   : 'variable',
  menu      :
            {
                newmenu:
                {
                    title : 'Menu', items : variablenames_concat,           
                }
            },
 content_css: 
            [
                '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i',
                '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css'
            ],
content_style:".variable{cursor:default;background-color:#65b9dd;color:#FFF;padding:2px;border-radius:3px;font-weight: bold;font-style:normal;display:inline-block;}",


setup        : function (editor)
                    {
                      eval(addmenu_concat);
                    }
});
</script>
```